# Deploying an Internal API

Tags: hosting, backend

I basically have an API that is going to be used with a web app and a mobile app. I don't want the API to publically available, where should I deploy it then? is there a way without using AWS? Thanks, Nav :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. This is a sensitive topic, as this is an opinion-based field.

However, I will try to answer below - and challange your way of approaching this.

It really depends on your 'operational' skills, funds, need for security, deadline(s) etc.

Basically you need to make an endpoint available on the www, without everybody being able to connect.

You could either:

- Deploy a virtual machine or web app. in Azure/AWS/GCP/... and whitelist the IP's you need to connect from.
- Rent a [VPS](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=VPS%20hosting&t=hk&ia=web) from any provider, and deploy your application here - Again, whitelisting. (Edit: Not phones, since this IP changes constantly. A proxy can be implemented here (potential bottleneck), or any authentication mechanism like OAuth, JWT, Certificates etc. can be implemented either on the ingress controller (e.g. NGINX) or the application itself.)
- Deploy the application on your Home-PC, order a static IP to your home and make a forwarded port and set up security on your premise **(not recommended, and raises and bunch of other headaches)**
- Get in touch with a company that hosts web applications (Can be quite expensive)

Based on the limited information provided in your question, there is a ton of options, nice-2-haves and factors that comes in to play when choosing the setup that suits your needs.

You should also consider; VPN usage, Backup/disaster recovery, data leaks, redundancy, the need for future deploys, how you would access your environment in six months....

I hope this answered your question, but also raised a few for you to answer yourself.

Finally, I'd recommend you looking for inspiration [here](https://geekflare.com/securing-api-endpoint/).

**EDIT:**

Question:
Whitelisting mobile IP's.
VPS selected.

Answer:

This becomes quite a task when mobile phones tend to change IP's frequently.
Since you are looking further into the VPS setup, you are more in control of the setup and can choose to look into OAuth and JWT.

Links:
OAuth - https://oauth.net/getting-started/  https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/01/22/oauth-api-keys-arent-safe-in-mobile-apps

NGINX JWT - https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-jwt-authentication/

So - At the end of the day, you can make your app use a proxy (potential bottleneck) and whitelist this IP, or make the endpoint open (any -> 443) and implement an authentication mechanism like the ones mentioned above.

Consider implementing a DMZ zone for incoming traffic from the web.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)
and put your application behind this zone, making sure that the only the DMZ zone is facing the internet, and the server hosting your application is talking to the server in the DMZ.
Again, this is quite a big topic and is hard to simplify to a stackoverflow post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for VPS, if I have a mobile app, each mobile have different IPs, how can I go about whitelisting all the IPs, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the app on AWS you have a couple of options.

API Gateway now supports private endpoints. These endpoints can not be called via the public internet. That means if your app is hosted on AWS only the internal services of the app can call the end point. i.e. front end to database etc. I've used this method for internal micro services such as placing in house app data onto kinesis streams.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use API Gateway you have lots of options. Most of which would involve you creating rest APIs from where ever you plan on hosting your code. This could be on the server it's self or some sort of container.

API Gateway Private Endpoint Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/